# Having trouble getting the scroll animation to not trigger the scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I currently have  a number of div tags that can be seen below that are each the height of the viewport.

```
<!-- .current represents the div the user is currently viewing -->
<div class="full-height current" id="id1">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id2">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id3">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id4">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id5">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to implement a feature where upon a user scrolling, the window will scroll to the next div tag, always having only one div in view at a time. The way I implemented it works great, except for the fact that the animation triggers the scroll event again, resulting in an endless loop of the page scrolling once the user scrolls at all. I attempted to fix this by having a variable that will stop the event from triggering if the animation is in progress, but it does not seem to work. I am aware that I didn't do it for the scroll up, but I just wanted to see if it worked for the down first.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    // If user scrolls down
    if ((scrollTop > lastScrollTop) && $(".current").next("div").length > 0) {
        if (animating == false) {
            console.log("down");

            $(".current").next("div").addClass("current");
            $(".current").first().removeClass("current");

            animating = true;
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top    
            }, 1000, function() {animating = false});   
        }
    // If user scrolls up
    } else {
        if ($(".current").prev("div").length > 0) {
            console.log("up");

            $(".current").prev("div").addClass("current");
            $(".current").last().removeClass("current");

            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top    
            }, 1000);
        }            
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

CSS included just in case. The 100vh - 111px is due to a fixed navbar at the top that is 111px high

```
/* Makes the element take up the entire height of the screen */
.full-height{
    height: -o-calc(100vh - 111px); /* opera */
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 111px); /* google, safari */
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 111px); /* firefox */
}

#id1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#id2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#id3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#id4 {
    background-color: green;
}

#id5 {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

If anyone could give me any ideas for fixing my problem, that would be great.

Comment: No `.current` elements appear at `html` ?

Comment: @guest271314 not sure what you mean by that

Comment: `html` at Question does not appear to contains elements having `class` `.current` , which is referenced at `scroll` event handler

Comment: The first div tag contains a .current class

Comment: Yes , you are correct. `lastScrollTop` would be `undefined` at initial scroll ?

Comment: I set it equal to 0 before the function.

Comment: The loop is caused by `animating = false` being set *just* before the last scroll. Check when a small timeout is put inside the callback : [**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwMxgV?editors=001). If you ask me, it's better done with mousewheel. You can't prevent the default action of `scroll`, it is itself the default. But you can with `wheel`, which defaults to scroll...

Comment: @SpeedOfSmell See post for a possible approach

Comment: Don't forget to add the non-prefixed version of calc in your CSS, after the prefixed versions

Comment: That's indeed the most important one... Opera never needed a prefix by the way. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to stop the event and preventDefault. Here is some code from a current landing page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
            var link = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(link.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
            }, 500);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
            offset: 80
        });

    });
```

It uses bootstrap scrollspy so just ignore that. But notice that it stops any  scroll animation that could be running and then also calls `event.preventDefault()` to stop the scroll event from bubbling and thus becoming recursive.

EDIT:

O.k. so I've a better look and the basic problem re: infinite scrolling is the code doesn't check if the scrollTop is already at 'where it needs to be'. You need an additional check to short circuit the scroll:

```
if (animating == false) {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() == lastScrollTop) return;

        if (($(this).scrollTop() > lastScrollTop) && $(".current").next("div")) {
        console.log("down");

        $(".current").next("div").addClass("current");
        $(".current").first().removeClass("current");

        animating = true;
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top
        }, 1000,
        function () { lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); animating = false; });

        // If user scrolls up
    } else {
        if ($(".current").prev("div").length > 0) {
            console.log("up");

            $(".current").prev("div").addClass("current");
            $(".current").last().removeClass("current");

            $("html, body").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top
            }, 1000, function () { lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); animating = false; });
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise as it stands it will always either scroll up or down and never settle. That said with that "working" it's a terrible user experience. It will jump about since your scroll to code will fight the user on current scrollTop if they keep scrolling. i.e. your code will make it jump back to a previous position.

Comment: I am a bit unclear on how to implement this. I changed the `.animate()` to `.stop().animate()` and added the `event.preventDefault()` but it still scrolls infinitely, just slowing down over time.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `scroll` event handler as named function ; defining `lastScrollTop` outside of `scroll` handler ; substituting `.one()` for `.on()` to allow animation to complete before re-attaching `scroll` event ; use `.promise()` which should be called at most once to avoid `.animate()` `complete` callback being called twice with selector `"html, body"` ; substituting single `if` to check for next or previous element `.length` and `.animate()` call for multiple `if..else` conditions and statements, animation function calls ; re-attach `scroll` event at `.then()` following animation completion `.promise()`

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

function scroller(event) {

  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var direction = scrollTop > lastScrollTop ? "next" : "prev";
  var el = $(".current")[direction](".full-height");
  console.log(direction === "next" ? "down" : "up");
  if (el.is("*")) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: el.offset().top
    }, 1000).promise().then(function() {
      console.log(this)
      lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      $(".current")
      .removeClass("current")[direction]("div")
      .addClass("current")
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).one("scroll", scroller)
      })
    });
  } else {
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    $(window).one("scroll", scroller)
  }
}

$(window).one("scroll", scroller);
```

```css
/* Makes the element take up the entire height of the screen */

.full-height {
  height: -o-calc(100vh - 111px);
  /* opera */
  height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 111px);
  /* google, safari */
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 111px);
  /* firefox */
}
#id1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#id2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#id3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#id4 {
  background-color: green;
}
#id5 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- .current represents the div the user is currently viewing -->
<div class="full-height current" id="id1">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id2">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id3">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id4">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full-height" id="id5">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shikkediel See updated post ; included `"html"` selector , substituted `.promise().then()` for  `.animate()` `complete` callback function

Answer (score 0):

If you define height 100vh ,scroll event wont trigger